# Count sizes of groups in time intervals around threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a threshold in pandas in the time dimension say

```
threshold = datetime(2022, 1, 3, 9)
```

And I have a dataframe with timestamps. I want to count how many of my datapoints fall in 15 minutes (say) intervals around the threshold.

So in this case where the threshold is 9 o'clock on January 3rd. I want to have how many observations are between ... 830 and 845, 845 and 9, 9 and 915, 915 and 930 etc.

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Convert the times to integer timestamps. Then you can use `np.floor(timestamp / 60 / 15)` to get the 15-minute period, and use that in `groupby()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.grouper` to group in 15 minutes (or whatever) time increments.

**Sample Data**

```
s_ts = datetime.datetime(2022,6,27,8)
e_ts = datetime.datetime(2022,6,27,11)
n = 30 

df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [faker.date_time_between(start_date=s_ts, end_date=e_ts) for _ in range(n)]} )
print(df.head())

                   ts
0 2022-06-27 08:22:21
1 2022-06-27 08:38:28
2 2022-06-27 10:27:56
3 2022-06-27 10:14:45
4 2022-06-27 09:04:47
```

**Then use `grouby` with `grouper`**

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='ts', freq="15T")).agg({'ts':'count'})
```

**Result**

```
                     ts
ts                     
2022-06-27 08:00:00   2
2022-06-27 08:15:00   4
2022-06-27 08:30:00   3
2022-06-27 08:45:00   2
2022-06-27 09:00:00   3
2022-06-27 09:15:00   2
2022-06-27 09:30:00   1
2022-06-27 09:45:00   2
2022-06-27 10:00:00   5
2022-06-27 10:15:00   4
2022-06-27 10:30:00   2
```

Note: you'd have to filter the time periods you want before or after the `groupby` for threshold using date arithmetic and selection.